# ASP.NET MVC4 - Remote validation on a collection object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, remote-validation

I'm at my wit's end trying to figure out a way to make this work. I have an ASP.NET MVC4 View which is strongly typed to a ViewModel which contains a number of collection objects. One of those objects is a list of column headers

```
public List<ColumnHeader> ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to simply qualify this member with a remote validation attribute like

```
[Remote("AreCustomExpressionsSafe", "Validation")]
```

Where I can then accept the entire collection as a parameter to the AreCustomExpressionsSafe action of my Validation controller to perform client-side validation on all of the members of that collection at once, with a single round trip to the server. Can anyone demonstrate the code that might be necessary to make this happen, probably in the View and in the ViewModel definition? Any help would be a complete life-saver--I'm really out of options.